# Django, send_mail, gets not enough values to unpack

Tags: python, django

Django, send_mail, gets not enough values to unpack, also tried
EmailMultiAlternatives, EmailMessage added traceback. the following
information hopefully will help you in your endeavors to find
solutions.

```
            ValueError at /accounts/password_reset/
            not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
            Request Method: POST
            Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_reset/
            Django Version: 3.1
            Exception Type: ValueError
            Exception Value:    
            not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
            Exception Location: d:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py, line 96, in sanitize_address
            Python Executable:  d:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\Scripts\python.exe
            Python Version: 3.9.1
```

class CustomResetPasswordView(PasswordResetView):
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
email = request.POST.get('email')
try:
_user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
if not _user:
raise Exception('Invalid email address!')
else:
context = {
'email'   : _user.email,
'domain'  : get_current_site(request).domain,
'uid'     : urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(_user.pk)),
'user'    : _user,
'token'   : default_token_generator.make_token(_user),
'protocol': 'https' if request.is_secure() else 'http',
}

```
               _superuser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).values_list('email').first()
               send_mail(
                    subject='Password Reset Request',
                    message=context,
                    from_email=_superuser,
                    recipient_list=[_user.email]
                )
        except Exception as e:
            raise
```

```
settings:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
    EMAIL_HOST = 'mail.smtp2go.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'confidential'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'confidential'
```

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/password_reset/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_python3_ldap',
 'DictionaryApp.apps.DictionaryappConfig',
 'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
 'crispy_forms']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 73, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 222, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 101, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\DictionaryApp\views.py", line 79, in post
    msg.send()
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 109, in send_messages
    sent = self._send(message)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 121, in _send
    from_email = sanitize_address(email_message.from_email, encoding)
  File "D:\Python\Code\dictionary\.env\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 96, in sanitize_address
    nm, address = addr

Exception Type: ValueError at /accounts/password_reset/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Please provide debugging details

Answer (score 0):

error was caused by the following line of code...
_superuser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).values_list('email').first()

I changed this to
_superuser =  User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True).first()
_superuser = _superuser.email

_msg.send was expecting the email as the first parameter, andnot the whole shooting match as I did originally.